# Getting time from jSpinner and storing it into database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jspinner

Hello everybody I just created jSpinner in swing to get time in this format (HH:mm:ss)  and store it into database, I customized the code, when I run the code the time appears correctly but I can't get the time and store it into database.

Here is my customized code:

```
Date date1 =new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm =
new SpinnerDateModel(date1 ,null, null,Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
start_time = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(start_time,"HH:mm:ss");
start_time.setEditor(de);
// Code adding the component to the parent container - not shown here
```

Comment: What did you try to get the time? Do you get any error messages? The code you presented is probably not sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: No there's no an error message... this code to show time in this format (HH:mm:ss) .... here is the command that inserts into database ...                 DatabeseConnection.myStmt.execute("insert into exam (eexamStartTime) values('"+start_time.getValue().toString()+"'););

Comment: A post should have one focused question. You are asking two: a. how to get time from a spinner ? b.how to store it in a database. Please decide which one and edit the post accordingly. Also, a name written in foreign  letters is not very helpful to those who can't read it.